# How to limit the frequency of Woocommerce orders

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm looking to limit the frequency of customers making an order on my WooCommerce website. I'd like them to be able to make an order once per week, starting and ending on Sunday night.

I'm new to Woocommerce so if you could please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Do you mean that the customer can only order once per week? Couldn't they create a new account and order again?

Comment: Why would you want to limit the number of orders? Please elaborate.

Comment: This is way too different requirement still have added an answer. do add your code which check for 2nd order in current week.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, sure you can do this by adding your logic to check if any orders within the current week or not.

I am using the following woocommerce filter so that a user will get an alert message when he tries and violets the condition and so will not be able to add that item to cart.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation','wdm_verify_product_limitation',5,4);

function wdm_verify_product_limitation($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations){

/*your Magic code to calculate whether this is the 2nd order in the current week*/
if ( /* Result of your magic code true if its not the 1st product of this week for the current user*/ ) {
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You are allowed to buy one product in a week.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed; 
}
```

You need to add this code in your child theme or your plugin so that it wont get deleted when a Theme/plugin updates.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I copied and pasted the above code in the functions.php file and the entire screen went blank (had to remove the code from the server directly to access the site again.)

Would there be a plugin that allows for this feature?

Comment: Hello Friend, you have to code the condition yourself in the snippet i provided in the answer. Your screen went blank because you didn't added your magic code(which will calculate and check for users limit). You do need to code that logic yourself.

Comment: Currently no plugin provides this feature as such. This can be achieve only through customization.